# I want to use text-style tags in django, but I don't want to be XSSed

Tags: django, xss

In the website on which I'm working, users may send messages to each other. I want users to be able to use text-style tags such as < b > , < i > , and < u > to make text bold, italic and underlined respectively. But, in fact, I don't want to be XSSed with those < script > tags. Or perhaps a < b > with a mouseover attribute.

What's the easiest and the most secure way to do so?

I'm using django and jQuery if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use HTML tags, you should consider using [Bleach](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach).

```
>>> evil = "This <script>...</script> is partly <b>evil</b>"
>>> bleach.clean(evil)
u'This &lt;script&gt;...&lt;/script&gt; is partly <b>evil</b>'
```

With `clean` you can explicitly whitelist the tags you want to allow. By using `strip` you also strip unallowed tags instead of escaping them:

```
>>> evil = "This uses <i>i</i> and <b title='hovertext'>b</b> and <em>em</em>"
>>> bleach.clean(evil, tags=["b"], attributes=dict(), strip=True)
u'This uses i and <b>b</b> and em'
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't allow tags. Instead use one of the markup languages [supported by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/markup/) which do not permit XSS attacks in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. A super clean and smart solution.